# In Sysinternals' livekd, how can we find the information associated with a process from its PID?

Tags: windows, windbg, sysinternals, livekd

I want to get information on a process from Sysinternals' livekd using its process ID. How do I do this?

The documentation for WinDBG's !process command on MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-process) says,

```
!process [/s Session] [/m Module] [Process [Flags]]
```

gives information about the process specified by "Process". The documentation further says,

> Process - Specifies the hexadecimal address or the process ID of the process on the target computer.

But try as I might, specifying the PID gives nothing, and I can't see a way to find the hexadecimal address of the process structure for a running process.

For e.g., from Sysinternals' Process Explorer, I see a process with PID 672 backed by svchost.exe, as follows:

[image]

But when I use the !process command with the PID 672 or its hexadecimal, 2A0, I get nothing. See below:

```
0: kd> !process 672
Searching for Process with Cid == 672
Cannot resolve nt!_EPROCESS object type
0: kd> !process 2A0
Searching for Process with Cid == 2a0
Cannot resolve nt!_EPROCESS object type
```

But `!process svchost.exe` works (for a some instance of that image that's running):

```
0: kd> !process svchost.exe
PROCESS ffffdc0a4b49b180
    SessionId: none  Cid: 0004    Peb: 00000000  ParentCid: 0000
    DirBase: 001ad002  ObjectTable: ffff9a0ba4e3ee40  HandleCount: 6664.
    Image: System
    VadRoot ffffdc0a66ea3200 Vads 58 Clone 0 Private 30. Modified 31341619. Locked 192.
    DeviceMap ffff9a0ba4e36360
    Token                             ffff9a0ba4e072b0
    ElapsedTime                       5 Days 13:59:48.702
```

I can also use `!process ffffdc0a4b49b180` using the information gained from `!process svchost.exe`, but I want to use the process ID to get this information. How do I do this?

**Edit 1**: I *think* that I am setting the symbols correctly, based on information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-path . Please see the output below.

```
0: kd> .sympath
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols\*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*c:\symbols\*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*c:\symbols\*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
0: kd> lml
start             end                 module name
fffff804`82200000 fffff804`83246000   nt         (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\1F9BB45B28B806E4D18925C06E924B8C1\ntkrnlmp.pdb
fffff804`a3420000 fffff804`a342d000   LiveKdD    (no symbols)           
0: kd> !sym noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts on
0: kd> .reload nt
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0xF
         c:\symbols\*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         ntoskrnl.exe
         F05723421046000
SYMSRV:  PATH: c:\symbols\ntoskrnl.exe\F05723421046000\ntoskrnl.exe
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\ntoskrnl.exe\F05723421046000\ntoskrnl.exe - OK
DBGENG:  c:\symbols\ntoskrnl.exe\F05723421046000\ntoskrnl.exe - Mapped image memory
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x10
         c:\symbols\*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         ntkrnlmp.pdb
         1F9BB45B28B806E4D18925C06E924B8C1
SYMSRV:  PATH: c:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\1F9BB45B28B806E4D18925C06E924B8C1\ntkrnlmp.pdb
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: nt - public symbols  
        c:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\1F9BB45B28B806E4D18925C06E924B8C1\ntkrnlmp.pdb
0: kd> dt nt!_EPROCESS
   +0x000 Pcb              : _KPROCESS
   +0x438 ProcessLock      : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x440 UniqueProcessId  : Ptr64 Void
   +0x448 ActiveProcessLinks : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x458 RundownProtect   : _EX_RUNDOWN_REF
   +0x460 Flags2           : Uint4B
   +0x460 JobNotReallyActive : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x460 AccountingFolded : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x460 NewProcessReported : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   ....
```

**Edit 2**:

I just discovered that LiveKdD.sys is not getting loaded. I have reinstalled  Windows SDK, and uninstalled my antivirus software. That doesn't fix this issue.

**But**, LivekdD.sys is present in the directory it's trying to load it from. See below.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers> dir livekdd.sys


    Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        24-11-2021     21:53          39272 livekdd.sys


Launching D:\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\kd.exe:

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22000.194 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\WINDOWS\livekd.dmp]
Kernel Complete Dump File: Full address space is available

Comment: 'LiveKD live system view'

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*c:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*c:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is:
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9200 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff807`75400000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff807`7602a2d0
Debug session time: Wed Nov 24 22:03:56.831 2021 (UTC + 5:30)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:13:04.851
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
..................................
Loading User Symbols
..........................................
Loading unloaded module list
............
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
0: kd> .tlist notepad.exe
Unable to load image \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\LiveKdD.SYS, Win32 error 0n2
 0n3176 notepad.exe
```

Comment: It works for me. Be wary that the default base is hexadecimal for the debugging engine (you can prefix a number with `0n` (e.g. `0n672`) to indicate it's in decimal). Do you have symbolic information available (at least the kernel one)? It seems it can't resolve `nt!_EPROCESS` which is available in the kernel symbols. See [`Symbol Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-path) from Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @Neitsa Thanks for the reply. I *think* I am setting the symbols right - I have updated the question with the relevant output. For e.g., I can run `dt nt!_EPROCESS` command and get the correct output. I am also able to get the process information by specifying the image name (i.e., `!process services.exe`).

Comment: It works for me, too. Which version of WinDbg do you use?

Comment: My WinDBG version is: WinDBG 10.0.22000.194 AMD64. Incidentally, I am using sysinternals livekd which (I think) generates a memory dump of the system and then loads it rather than working on the live OS. I am not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: It works for me with livekd (but I have a slightly older windbg version). Does it still complains about the missing `_EPROCESS` when you `!process <pid>` (even if you can `dt` that structure)? If not what's the new error message (if there's one)?

Comment: I get the error, "Cannot resolve nt!_EPROCESS object type" when I do `!process <pid>`. I just discovered that an error I get at the startup is unusual. I will try reinstalling a few things and see if that fixes things.

Answer (score 2):

As Already commented several times it works
here is an output from livekd

```
0: kd> .tlist calculator.exe
 0n1872 Calculator.exe
0: kd> !process 0n1872 0
Searching for Process with Cid == 750
PROCESS ffffc388a8cd5080
    SessionId: 5  Cid: 0750    Peb: 806522f000  ParentCid: 0250
    DirBase: 7a081002  ObjectTable: ffff8985feda39c0  HandleCount: 467.
    Image: Calculator.exe

0: kd> !process 0 0 calculator.exe
PROCESS ffffc388a8cd5080
    SessionId: 5  Cid: 0750    Peb: 806522f000  ParentCid: 0250
    DirBase: 7a081002  ObjectTable: ffff8985feda39c0  HandleCount: 467.
    Image: Calculator.exe
```

EDIT

a complete session

```
D:\>livekd

LiveKd v5.63 - Execute kd/windbg on a live system
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Copyright (C) 2000-2020 Mark Russinovich and Ken Johnson

Launching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\kd.exe:

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\WINDOWS\livekd.dmp]
Kernel Complete Dump File: Full address space is available

Comment: 'LiveKD live system view'

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*f:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*f:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is:
Windows 8 Kernel Version 9200 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff803`3cc00000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff803`3d045f30
Debug session time: Wed Nov 24 06:55:11.500 2021 
System Uptime: 3 days 5:19:28.286
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
..................................................
0: kd> .tlist cmd.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for LiveKdD.SYS
 0n7836 cmd.exe
0: kd> !process 0n7836 0
Searching for Process with Cid == 1e9c
PROCESS ffffc388b2810080
    SessionId: 9  Cid: 1e9c    Peb: 7f78344000  ParentCid: 1468
    DirBase: 115d4a002  ObjectTable: ffff8985fed9ad40  HandleCount:  68.
    Image: cmd.exe

0: kd>
```

edit 2

my module is as follows

```
0: kd> lmv live
start             end                 module name
fffff803`59090000 fffff803`5909d000   LiveKdD    (no symbols)
    Symbol file: LiveKdD.SYS
    Image path: \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\LiveKdD.SYS
    Image name: LiveKdD.SYS
    Timestamp:        Mon Apr 27 21:28:28 2020 (5EA70124)
    CheckSum:         00014362
    ImageSize:        0000D000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
    Information from resource tables:
0: kd>
```

Comment: Thanks. 

Are you getting the message "Unable to load image \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\LiveKdD.SYS, Win32 error 0n2" when you start LiveKD?  The LiveKD documentation says that WinDBG will complain that it can't find the *symbols* for LiveKD, but I just want to check that my error message is what is expected.

Comment: no symbol error message will be like 0: kd> .reload /f
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for LiveKdD.SYS  you have module load error not symbol load error try redownloading

Comment: added a complete session with versions of both livekd and kd visible for ref

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Apparently, the LiveKdD.SYS file is present in the `c:\windows\system32\drivers` directory. It's just not getting loaded, with the error message, 0n02 (file not found). livekd is trying to load this file using the path `\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\Drivers\LiveKdD.SYS` . Will the path with the \?? appended cause an issue? (Please see the question with the appended output). Thanks again.

Comment: you have installed sdk and debuggers in non standard path (not in c:\programfiles x86\....) D:\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\kd.exe i dont know i noramlly leave ms thingies at ms defaut place edited answer to add module details

Comment: Thanks. I just installed it in the normal directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits), but that didn't fix the issue unfortunately.